# Freebase returning empty results for MQL query of topic description

Tags: google-api, freebase

I try and use the google API freebase.
I search for films description using the following query:

```
[{ 
  "id": "/m/027pfg", 
  "name": null, 
  "/common/topic/description": [] 
}]
```

which result in :

```
{ 
  "result": [{ 
    "id": "/m/027pfg", 
    "name": "Big Fish", 
    "/common/topic/description": [] 
  }] 
}
```

the url:

> http://www.freebase.com/query?autorun=1&q=%5B%7B%22id%22:%22/m/027pfg%22,%22name%22:null,%22/common/topic/description

but in the page itself: "http://www.freebase.com/m/027pfg" 
I do see the description of the film. 
this happenes alot and I can not get the info I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [MQL API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/mql-overview) does not return entity descriptions. In order to get the descriptions, you'll need to use either the [Search API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search-overview) or the [Topic API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/topic-overview).

Search API:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=/m/027pfg&output=(description)
```

Topic API:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/027pfg?filter=/common/topic
```

Comment: thank you. do you know maybe how can I get info about all movies in their Api consecutively?

Comment: Freebase has information on over 200,000 movies right now.  The data dumps are probably the best way to get them all. https://developers.google.com/freebase/data

Comment: I downloaded the tsv file. Can you tell me please What would the best way to approach the data and parse it?

Comment: Can you please post that as a separate question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476981/google-api-freebase-data-dumps-parsing-using-c-sharp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537725/freebase-google-api-data-dumps-seatrching-for-all-films