# Google Api FreeBase data dumps parsing using c#

Tags: c#, google-api, freebase, data-dump

I want to search the google Api freebase. I want to get general amount of data. For example all Ids of songs, or films. I downloaded the data dumps gz file. I wonder what will be the best solution of parsing the file and getting the data I need. I am using .net c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple .NET libraries that can read the RDF format of the dumps:

- [SemWeb.NET](http://razor.occams.info/code/semweb/)
- [dotNetRdf](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/)

The data dumps are also formatted as tab separated values so you should be able to use any CSV parser to parse each line as a triple.

Make sure that you read through the [developer docs](https://developers.google.com/freebase/data) on how the data dumps are formatted. Basically, each line forms a triple that has a subject, predicate and object. To get all the data about films you'll be looking for triples that have a predicate that starts with /film/.

Comment: I tried using an already made parser like CsvReader and it raised error : "An unhandled exception of type 'LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv.MalformedCsvException' occurred in LumenWorks.Framework.IO.dll".  any ideas?

Comment: Did you tell it to separate on tabs rather than commas? Also you might need to tell it to skip over the first couple of lines where the prefix headers are. That error message could be anything though.

Comment: can you please tell me how tp search for actors or directors please?

Comment: I would also love to get imdb ids from the Api.

Comment: this is the query I want http://www.freebase.com/query?autorun=1&q=%22id%22:%22/m/0bth54%22,%22name%22:null,%22/film/film/imdb_id%22:[]  and when I try to search the google api to return json it raise error with this url: https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query={{%22/film/film/imdb_id%22:[],%22id%22:%22/m/027pfg%22}}   What am I doing wrong??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508206/google-freebase-api-problems-with-querying

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537725/freebase-google-api-data-dumps-seatrching-for-all-films

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523027/trying-to-get-wiki-id-from-the-freebase-api