# Google FreeBase Api - problems with querying

Tags: google-api, freebase

I am trying to query the google freebase Api. this is the query I want: [http://www.freebase.com/query?autorun=1&q=%22id%22:%22/m/0bth54%22,%22/film/film/imdb_id%22:[]](http://www.freebase.com/query?autorun=1&q=%22id%22%3a%22/m/0bth54%22,%22/film/film/imdb_id%22%3a%5B%5D) and when I try to search the google api to return json it raise error with this url: 
[googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query={{%22/film/film/imdb_id%22:‌[],%22id%22:%22/m/027pfg%22}}](http://googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=%7B%7B%22/film/film/imdb_id%22%3a%E2%80%8C%5B%5D,%22id%22%3a%22/m/027pfg%22%7D%7D) .  What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three things wrong:

- wrong protocol - must be `https::`
- missing subdomain - `www.`
- invalid JSON in query

If you click on the `Link` button in the query editor from your first URL, it'll give you an MQLread URL that you can just cut and paste:

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread/?lang=%2Flang%2Fen&query=%5B%7B+%22id%22%3A+%22%2Fm%2F0bth54%22%2C+%22%2Ffilm%2Ffilm%2Fimdb_id%22%3A+%5B%5D+%7D%5D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537725/freebase-google-api-data-dumps-seatrching-for-all-films

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523027/trying-to-get-wiki-id-from-the-freebase-api