# Freebase Google data dumps searching for all films

Tags: google-api, freebase

I am trying to work with Freebase data dumps. I try to get only the films Ids by searching the predicates that starts with "film.film". But like that I got alot of unrelated items. 
this is a predicate for example:

> film.film_character.portrayed_in_films_dubbed..film.dubbing_performance.film

which brings Id of this url:

> http://www.freebase.com/m/0pc731y

which is not a movie but a character in a movie.
Can anybody help me please???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do a prefix search, you're going to get anything which matches the prefix.

If you want IMDB ids, like your other question, you could search for:

```
ns:type.object.key\t"/authority/imdb/title
```

If you want all subject IDs of type film, you could search for:

```
rdf:type\tns:film\.film\.$
```

In other words, make your search expression match what you're trying to find.

Comment: can you help me please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532534/gettting-actor-ids-and-biographies-from-the-data-dumps-or-freebase-api